# Laravel complex query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have the following tables:

**Dishes**

```
id
name
```

**Customers**

```
id
name
```

**Ingredients**

```
id
name
```

**Dishes_Ingredients** (table to put in relation dishes and ingredients)

```
id
dish_id
ingredient_id
```

**Customers_Allergic_Ingredients** (customers are allergic to certain ingredients)

```
id
customer_id
ingredient_id
```

**Customers_Intolerance_Ingredients** (customers are intolerant to certain ingredients)

```
id
customer_id
ingredient_id
```

I need to get the following information from the database: for a given `customer_id`, I want to retrieve all the dishes which the customer is **not** allergic to and not intolerant to, using Laravel Query Builder.

This is what I tried so far:

```
$dishes = DB::table('dishes')
           ->join('dishes_ingredients', 'dishes.id', '=', 'dishes_ingredients.dish_id')
           ->join('customers_allergic_ingredients', 'dishes_ingredients.ingredient_id', '<>', 'customers_allergic_ingredients.ingredient_id')
           ->join('customers_intolerance_ingredients', 'dishes_ingredients.ingredient_id', '<>', 'customers_intolerance_ingredients.ingredient_id')
           ->where('customers.id', 1)
           ->select('dishes.id', 'dish_translations.name')
           ->get();
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place to get a complex solution if you're not even try a bit. First learn few topics (SQL, PHP, Laravel) then try... If it won't work then try again... and after that come here and place your question...

Comment: Pls edit your code with what you tried. Then we'll able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Laravel but if you just want to solve your problem:

```
SELECT *
FROM Dishes d
WHERE d.id NOT IN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT dish_id
        FROM Dishes_Ingridients
        WHERE ingredient_id IN
            (SELECT DISTINCT ingredient_id FROM Customers_Allergic_Ingredients cai WHERE cai.customer_id = ?)
            OR
            ingredient_id IN
            (SELECT DISTINCT ingredient_id FROM Customers_Intolerance_Ingredients cii WHERE cii.customer_id = ?)
    )
```

Comment: I tried this query:
`SELECT *
 FROM dishes
 INNER JOIN dishes_ingredients
 ON dishes.id = dishes_ingredients.dish_id
 WHERE dishes_ingredients.ingredient_id NOT IN
   (SELECT cai.ingredient_id FROM customers_allergic_ingredients cai WHERE cai.customer_id = 1)
 AND dishes_ingredients.ingredient_id NOT IN
   (SELECT cii.ingredient_id FROM customers_intolerance_ingredients cii WHERE cii.customer_id = 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **Laravel Eloquent: Relationships**

this will save your time & your code will be more simply....

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Any idea on how to do that using Eloquent?

Answer (score 0):

```
  $dishes = DB::table("dishes AS a") 
                   ->select(array("a.*" ))
                   ->join("dishes_ingredients AS b", "a.id",  "b.dish_id") 
                   ->join("Customers_Allergic_Ingredients AS c", "b.id", "=", "c.ingredient_id")
                   ->where("c.customer_id", "!=", $customer_id) 
                   ->groupBy("a.id")
                   ->get();
```

This will give you all dishes made with ingredients that the customer is not allergic to